# Sum of data in a dimension by comparing data in two other dimensions in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I got stuck at a point where I need to find sum of the data of one dimension by using the data indexed by other two dimensions.

Example:

```
"mode_device","method","discount","time","first_time","paid","p_id","p_sku"
"Desktop","EBS",,"1344887090","1344887090","1079","8786","PPLB03571285"
"Desktop","MOBIKWIK-WALLET","89","1474371140","1474371140","591","99068","PPLB009DCBBFREE"
"AndroidApp","COD","97","1474371149","1438844849","647","72321","PPLB034601"
"Desktop","JUSPAY","60","1474371158","1474371158","398","92389","PPLB713SQ306"
"AndroidApp","COD","190","1474371247","1448993680","1261","72685","PLB0029regenerist3"
"Desktop","JUSPAY","90","1474371346","1474371346","599","86728","PPLB66719804817"
"Desktop","DEBITCARD","60","1474371366","1465733603","398","92389","PPLB713SQ306"
"AndroidApp","COD","0","1474371404","1474371404","577","106032","PPLB0335PA0990NM"
"Desktop","COD","43","1474371404","1468956726","356","13221","PPLB039605"
```

Here we compare `mode_device` and `method` and we have to return the sum of the data from the paid.

Example:
AndroidApp and COD may repeat for several times lets say data has something like

```
"Android","COD","234"
"Android","Ebs","234"
"Ios","COD","234"
"Ios","COD","234"
"Android","COD","234"
```

We have to return like

```
Android-COD:468
Android-Ebs:234
Ios-COD:468
```

using dc.js graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear from your question how you want to plot this data - will it be a bar chart with bars that are labeled with both fields?

But if you want to aggregate by both `mode_device` and `method`, you can simply create a dimension which uses both values in its key:

```
var modeMethodDimension = cf.dimension(function(d) { return [d.mode_device, d.method].join('-'); });
var modeMethodGroup = modeMethodDimension.group(function(d) { return +d.paid; });
```

Now the group should have key value pairs like

```
[{key: 'Android-COD', value: 468}, {key: 'Android-Ebs', value: 234}, ...]
```

and if you put it into a `dc.barChart` those keys would be the names of the bars.